# Jenkins -> Looping trough Docker-Agents

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, agent

I want to build some Packages using several **Docker-Images** in a **Jenkins-Pipeline**
. The Pipeline below works .. but I want to implement the Stage(s) is a more "Loop"-ish way ....

```
pipeline {
  
  agent { label 'docker' }

  stages {

    stage ('Running on ubuntu:20.04') {
      agent {
        docker {
          reuseNode true
          label 'docker'
          image 'ubuntu:20.04'
        }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'uname -a && bash --version'
      }
    }

    stage ('Running on ubuntu:22.04') {
      agent {
        docker {
          reuseNode true
          label 'docker'
          image 'ubuntu:22.04'
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'uname -a && bash --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An Ideas how to implement that ? ..

Initially I tried using something like this

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }

  stages {
    stage ('Loop-Stage') {
      steps {
        script {
     
          // Loop trough List (*works*)
          for (item in ['ubuntu:20.04', 'ubuntu:22.04']) {
            
            // Create new stage (*works*)
            stage ('Running on ${item}') {
              
              // Set agent (*fails*)
              agent {
                docker {
                  reuseNode true
                  label 'docker'
                  image "${item}"
                }
              }

              steps {
                sh 'uname -a && bash --version'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this does now work. The Error seems to indicate a mixture between scripted&declarative Syntax .. you get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, addInteractivePromotion, ansiColor, archive, artifactoryBuildTrigger, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryEditProps, artifactoryGoPublish, ar
```

How can I apply a the corresponding "agent" to the dynamically generated Stage ?

Answer (score 3):

When you go into a script block you can no longer use some of the declarative syntaxes like `agent`. That's why you are getting the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent'`. Jenkins is confused about whether you are trying to use Declarative Pipeline syntax or just scripted syntax with groovy.

You can do something like this. This will create a list of stages and then execute them in parallel.

```
def stageList

def getStages(image) {
    return {
        stage("Running on Ubunt:${image}") {
          docker.image("ubuntu:${image}").inside {
                sh 'uname -a'
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
agent any
  stages {
      
    stage ("Generate Stages") {
        steps {
            script {
                def imageList = ["20.04", "22.04"]
                stageList = imageList.collectEntries {
                        ["${it}" : getStages(it)]}
                    }
                
            }
        }

        stage("Run Stages") {
            steps {
                    script {
                        parallel stageList
                    }
                }
        }
        
    }
}
```

If you want sequential execution, you can modify your pipeline as shown below.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }

  stages {
    stage ('Loop-Stage') {
      steps {
        script {
     
          // Loop trough List (*works*)
          for (item in ['ubuntu:20.04', 'ubuntu:22.04']) {
            
            // Create new stage (*works*)
            stage ('Running on ${item}') {
              
            docker.image("${item}").inside {
                sh 'uname -a'
                sh 'uname -a && bash --version'
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most of your questions have answers here https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow and here : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: Thank you very much .. that what I was missing ..